Flutter - Bluetooth devices not showing on apk
I am rather new to flutter but couldn't find an easy solution for this.. I am using Flutter Blue Plus as a package to scan for bluetooth devices but no devices are appearing on my phone. here is the current code i made so far in the main.dart file.
Also when testing the app on my phone, I haven't set a prompt for the user permissions to scan nearby devices but I have done this manually by going to my phones app settings and enabling all premissions for the app.
Also here are the premissions I have set in the android build..
AndroidManifest.xml
    <!-- Tell Google Play Store that your app uses Bluetooth LE
    Set android:required="true" if bluetooth is necessary -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="false" />

<!-- New Bluetooth permissions in Android 12
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/features/bluetooth-permissions -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" />

<!-- legacy for Android 11 or lower -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:maxSdkVersion="30" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="30"/>

<!-- legacy for Android 9 or lower -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:maxSdkVersion="28" />

Main.dart file
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}







class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String appBarTitle = 'My App';
  List<ScanResult> foundDevices = [];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    blth_controller();
  }

  Future<void> blth_controller() async {
    var subscription =
        FlutterBluePlus.adapterState.listen((BluetoothAdapterState state) {
      print(state);

      if (state == BluetoothAdapterState.on) {
        print('bluetooth adapter is on');

        var scan = FlutterBluePlus.onScanResults.listen((results) {
          if (results.isNotEmpty) {
            print('found bluetooth devices');

            setState(() {
              appBarTitle = 'Device Found';
              foundDevices = results;
            });
          } else {
            print('no bluetooth devices found');

            setState(() {
              appBarTitle = 'No Device Found';
              foundDevices = [];
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        print('bluetooth adapter is off');
      }
    });
  }

It's supposed to render the scanned devices from the stream to my listview builder. shown below
 child: ListView.builder(
            itemCount: foundDevices.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, position) {
              var item = {


              'name': foundDevices[position].device.platformName,
              'distance': foundDevices[position].rssi.toString(),

                
              };

              Color circledistancecolor = Colors.white;

              int rssi = int.parse(item['distance']!);

              Color color;
              if (rssi > -50) {
                color = Colors.green;
              } else if (rssi > -60) {
                color = Colors.yellow;
              } else {
                color = Colors.red;
              }

